CollectionView doesn't work when ContentPage is inside Caroussel
I've a ContentPage which have a CollectionView which shows results from a table, the code works perfectly fine, the results are loaded and displayed.
But when I add this ContentPage to a Caroussel, it doesn't works anymore, it loads the results, but doesn't display in UI
This's my XAML code from my Carousel (partial):
        <!-- Carousel View -->
    <CarouselView x:Name="carouselView"
                          Grid.Row="4"
                          IsBounceEnabled="True"
                          IsScrollAnimated="True"
                          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                          Loop="False"
                          IndicatorView="indicadorView"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          CurrentItemChanged="OnCurrentItemChanged"
                          Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentPage}">
                <local:ValoresAditivo Title="Valores"/>
                <local:TabelaDocumentos Title="Documentos"/>
                <local:TabelaDevolvidos Title="Devolvidos"/>
                <local:TabelaPagamentos Title="Pagamentos"/>
            </x:Array>
        </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   FontSize="Large"
                                   TextColor="White"/>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>

This's my c# code from my Caroussel (partial):
public ObservableCollection<ContentPage> Pages { get; set; }
public ValoresAditivo ValoresAditivoPage { get; set; }
public TabelaDocumentos TabelaDocumentosPage { get; set; }
public TabelaDevolvidos TabelaDevolvidosPage { get; set; }
public TabelaPagamentos TabelaPagamentosPage { get; set; }

    public AditivosCarousel()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Outras Páginas
    ValoresAditivoPage = new ValoresAditivo();
    TabelaDocumentosPage = new TabelaDocumentos();
    TabelaDevolvidosPage = new TabelaDevolvidos();
    TabelaPagamentosPage = new TabelaPagamentos();


    Pages =
    [
        ValoresAditivoPage,
        TabelaDocumentosPage,
        TabelaDevolvidosPage,
        TabelaPagamentosPage
    ];

    carouselView.ItemsSource = Pages;
}
private void OnCurrentItemChanged(object sender, CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedPage = e.CurrentItem as ContentPage;
    if (selectedPage != null)
    {
        contentArea.Content = selectedPage.Content;

        // Se for resumo contrato, então chamar função para carregar dados
        // if (selectedPage is TabelaDocumentos tabelaDocumentosPage)
        // {
        //     tabelaDocumentosPage.BindingContext = tabelaDocumentosPage.viewModel;
        //     LoadTabela(16);
        // }

    }
}
private async void NroAditivoValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Verifique se o componente foi inicializado e se o entryNumeroCliente contém um número não nulo
    if (entryNumeroAdt != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entryNumeroAdt.Text) && int.TryParse(entryNumeroAdt.Text, out _))
    {
        if (resultsAdts != null)
        {
            var filteredResults = resultsAdts.Results.Where(r => r.Aditivo == stepperNumeroAdt.Value).ToList();

            if (filteredResults.Any())
            {
                // Carregar todos os dados do aditivo
                var aditivo = filteredResults.First();
                var ID_Aditivo = aditivo.ID_Aditivo ?? 0;

                // Exemplo de como você pode atualizar os controles com os valores filtrados
                ValoresAditivoPage.CarregarValores(Convert.ToInt64(stepperNumeroAdt.Value), aditivo);

                // Carregar Documentos
                await TabelaDocumentosPage.LoadTabela(ID_Aditivo);              

                // Carregar Devolvidos
                await TabelaDevolvidosPage.LoadTabela(ID_Aditivo);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Nenhum resultado encontrado com Aditivo igual a " + stepperNumeroAdt.Value + ".");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("resultsAdts não foi inicializado.");
        }
    }
}

This's my ContentPage LoadDocumento cs code:
public partial class TabelaDocumentos : ContentPage
{
    private DocumentosViewModel viewModel;

    private ObservableCollection<SearchResultAditivoDocumentos> AditivosDocumentos;

    public TabelaDocumentos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new DocumentosViewModel();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    public async Task LoadTabela(long ID_Aditivo)
    {
        // Limpar Tabela
        viewModel.AditivosDocumentos.Clear();
        
        // Se não existir um aditivo
        if (ID_Aditivo == 0) return;
        
        try
        {
            // Carregar Documentos
            Debug.WriteLine("ID_Aditivo: " + ID_Aditivo.ToString());
        
            var documentos = await PesquisarDB.SearchAditivoDocumentosAsync(ID_Aditivo.ToString());
            if (documentos != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in documentos)
                {
                    viewModel.AditivosDocumentos.Add(item);
                }
            }
        
            Debug.WriteLine("Quantidade linhas tabela Documentos: " + viewModel.AditivosDocumentos.Count.ToString());

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(viewModel.AditivosDocumentos));  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Erro ao carregar tabela documentos. Erro: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private async void Teste_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       await LoadTabela(16);
    }
}

And It's XAML Binding:
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AditivosDocumentos}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

ContentPage inside Caroussel (doesn't works):

ContentPage not inside Caroussel (works):


Did you try to use the ContentView instead of ContentPage in the CarouselView?

pages aren't intended to be nested inside of a Carousel or other view.  You also appear to be setting ContentArea manually and overwriting the template, which is strange and a sign that you are going about this the wrong way.

I really don't know exactly what I'm doing, this's my first App, I searched about Caroussel and I got this example... @Jason

You're following a bad example.  The ItemsSource should really be a collection of models, not UI elements.  The UI is laid out using the DataTemplate, and the data from the ItemsSource is then used to populate the UI.

I'm searching in google for another example of caroussel @Jason

the official docs contain a sample, and there are many questions on the subject on SO

Another thing is that you set the ItemsSource twice. Either in XAML or code behind is  okay.
